# Why my connected components were re-rendering even when mapStateToProps returned identical (===) props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've tried react-redux 6.0.0 and my connected components were re-rendering even when mapStateToProps returned identical (===) props. Is it a bug?

Confirmed it's specific to v6. Rolled back to 5.1.1 and those re-renders don't happen.

---

Video demonstration: [youtube](https://youtu.be/VvxN43XyMgo)

Src: [github](https://github.com/carceri/db/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting whatever those flashing outlines were.

I added a log statement to `Card.js`, loaded the page, then clicked on each of the three cards.  I got this output:

```
App.js:20 <App /> render
12:54:17.198 List.js:9 cardIDs: (3) [64, 1512, 900]
12:54:17.203 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card One
12:54:17.209 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card Two
12:54:17.210 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card Three
12:54:17.211 Deck.js:8 deckCardsIDs: []
12:54:23.108 Deck.js:8 deckCardsIDs: [64]
12:54:23.109 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card One
12:54:23.780 Deck.js:8 deckCardsIDs: (2) [64, 900]
12:54:23.782 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card Three
12:54:24.460 Deck.js:8 deckCardsIDs: (3) [64, 900, 1512]
12:54:24.462 Card.js:5 Card rendering: Card Two
```

This indicates that all three instances of `<Card>` rendered on startup, and then only the new added component instances rendered on each click.

In addition, I used the React DevTools Profiler to capture the update pattern on the clicks, which looked like this:

[image]

You can see that only a couple of the components actually updated.

v6 [does have a different internal implementation than v5](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/), but it should have the same general behavior overall.

Comment: thank you so much for answering!

I thought every components got re-rendering. But it turns out that it's not.